# Закрытие программы через 5 минут работы

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, реестр, qtimer

Следующая ситуация: мне нужно каким-то образом, с помощью реестра закрыть программу через **`5`** минут работы и попросить, например, купить прайм-подписку.

Максимум, что у меня вышло - это реализовать закрытие через определённо кол-во запусков.

```
import winreg
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
number, start_program = "", True


def software():
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as hkey:
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "SOFTWARE") as sub_key:
            try:
                i = 0
                while True:
                    path_value = winreg.EnumKey(sub_key, i)
                    print(f"{path_value}")
                    i += 1
            except OSError:
                print()
        winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
    winreg.CloseKey(hkey)


def read_key_software():
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as hkey:
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run") as sub_key:
            try:
                i = 0
                while True:
                    path_value = winreg.EnumValue(sub_key, i)
                    print(f"{path_value}")
                    i += 1
            except OSError:
                print("")
        winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
    winreg.CloseKey(hkey)


def matherboard():
    name_board = "BaseBoardProduct"
    n_b = True
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as hkey:
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\BIOS") as sub_key:
            try:
                i = 0
                while n_b:
                    path_value = winreg.EnumValue(sub_key, i)
                    if name_board == path_value[0]:
                        print(f"Matherboard: {path_value[1]}")
                        n_b = False
                    else:
                        i += 1
            except OSError:
                print("matherboard not found")
        winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
    winreg.CloseKey(hkey)
    print("")


def processor():
    name_proc = "ProcessorNameString"
    n_p = True
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as hkey:
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\CentralProcessor\\0") as sub_key:
            try:
                i = 0
                while n_p:
                    path_value = winreg.EnumValue(sub_key, i)
                    if name_proc == path_value[0]:
                        print(f"Proseccor: {path_value[1]}")
                        n_p = False
                    else:
                        i += 1
            except OSError:
                print("processor not found")
        winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
    winreg.CloseKey(hkey)
    print("")


def SPLab():
    global number, start_program
    path = False
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER) as hkey:
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "SOFTWARE") as sub_key:
            winreg.CreateKey(sub_key, "SPLab")
    winreg.CloseKey(hkey)
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER) as hkey:
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "SOFTWARE\\SPLab", 0, winreg.KEY_READ) as sub_key:
            try:
                num = winreg.EnumValue(sub_key, 0)
                path = True
                start = num[1]
                if int(start) >= 10:
                    start_program = False
            except OSError:
                path = False
        winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "SOFTWARE\\SPLab", 0, winreg.KEY_WRITE) as sub_key:
            if path:
                start = int(start) + 1
            else:
                start = "1"
            winreg.SetValueEx(sub_key, "NamberOfStarts", 0, winreg.REG_SZ, str(start))
        winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
    winreg.CloseKey(hkey)
    number = start
    print("")


class mainWin(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWin, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Program")

        if start_program:
            self.setGeometry(1000, 300, 580, 270)
            self.setStyleSheet("background : lightyellow;")
            self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.b1.setGeometry(20, 20, 250, 70)
            self.b1.setStyleSheet("background : lightgreen; font-size : 20px")
            self.b1.setText("software")
            self.b1.clicked.connect(software)
            self.b2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.b2.setGeometry(300, 20, 250, 70)
            self.b2.setStyleSheet("background : lightgreen; font-size : 20px")
            self.b2.setText("read_key_software")
            self.b2.clicked.connect(read_key_software)
            self.b3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.b3.setGeometry(20, 120, 250, 70)
            self.b3.setStyleSheet("background : lightgreen; font-size : 20px")
            self.b3.setText("matherboard")
            self.b3.clicked.connect(matherboard)
            self.b4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.b4.setGeometry(300, 120, 250, 70)
            self.b4.setStyleSheet("background : lightgreen; font-size : 20px")
            self.b4.setText("processor")
            self.b4.clicked.connect(processor)
            self.l5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            self.l5.setGeometry(20, 210, 250, 50)
            self.l5.setText(f"Number of starts: {number}")
            self.l5.setStyleSheet("font-size : 20px")
        else:
            self.setGeometry(800, 400, 850, 300)
            self.setStyleSheet("background : white;")
            self.l1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            self.l1.setGeometry(25, 100, 1000, 70)
            self.l1.setText("Buy the full version of the program!")
            self.l1.setStyleSheet("font-size : 50px")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SPLab()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mwin = mainWin()
    mwin.show()
    print("")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: попробуйте библиотеку datetime

Comment: @DisanD_08 это понятно, но не знаю как это в коде реализовать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс `QTimer` предоставляет повторяющиеся и однократные таймеры.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html

В моем примере сработает через 5 секунд, установите нужное вам время.

```
import winreg
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from PyQt5.Qt import *                                # +++

number, start_program = "", True


def software():
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as hkey:
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "SOFTWARE") as sub_key:
            try:
                i = 0
                while True:
                    path_value = winreg.EnumKey(sub_key, i)
                    print(f"{i} - {path_value}")
                    i += 1
            except OSError as e:
                print(f'OSError: ------------- {e}')
        winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
    winreg.CloseKey(hkey)


def read_key_software():
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as hkey:
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run") as sub_key:
            try:
                i = 0
                while True:
                    path_value = winreg.EnumValue(sub_key, i)
                    print(f"{path_value}")
                    i += 1
            except OSError:
                print("")
        winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
    winreg.CloseKey(hkey)


def matherboard():
    name_board = "BaseBoardProduct"
    n_b = True
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as hkey:
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\BIOS") as sub_key:
            try:
                i = 0
                while n_b:
                    path_value = winreg.EnumValue(sub_key, i)
                    if name_board == path_value[0]:
                        print(f"Matherboard: {path_value[1]}")
                        n_b = False
                    else:
                        i += 1
            except OSError:
                print("matherboard not found")
        winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
    winreg.CloseKey(hkey)
    print("")


def processor():
    name_proc = "ProcessorNameString"
    n_p = True
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as hkey:
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\CentralProcessor\\0") as sub_key:
            try:
                i = 0
                while n_p:
                    path_value = winreg.EnumValue(sub_key, i)
                    if name_proc == path_value[0]:
                        print(f"Proseccor: {path_value[1]}")
                        n_p = False
                    else:
                        i += 1
            except OSError:
                print("processor not found")
        winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
    winreg.CloseKey(hkey)
    print("")


def SPLab():
    global number, start_program
    path = False
    
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER) as hkey:
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "SOFTWARE") as sub_key:
            winreg.CreateKey(sub_key, "SPLab")
    winreg.CloseKey(hkey)
    
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER) as hkey:
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "SOFTWARE\\SPLab", 0, winreg.KEY_READ) as sub_key:
            try:
                num = winreg.EnumValue(sub_key, 0)
                path = True
                start = num[1]
                if int(start) >= 10:
                    start_program = False
            except OSError:
                path = False
        winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "SOFTWARE\\SPLab", 0, winreg.KEY_WRITE) as sub_key:
            if path:
                start = int(start) + 1
            else:
                start = "1"
                
            winreg.SetValueEx(sub_key, "NamberOfStarts", 0, winreg.REG_SZ, str(start))
            
        winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
    winreg.CloseKey(hkey)
    number = start
    print("")


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Program")
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget(self)                       # +++
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)                # +++
        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)       # +++

        if start_program:
            self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.b1, 1, 1)            # +++
            self.b1.setText("software")
            self.b1.clicked.connect(software)
            
            self.b2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.b2, 1, 2)            # +++
            self.b2.setText("read_key_software")
            self.b2.clicked.connect(read_key_software)
            
            self.b3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.b3, 2, 1)            # +++
            self.b3.setText("matherboard")
            self.b3.clicked.connect(matherboard)
            
            self.b4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.b4, 2, 2)            # +++
            self.b4.setText("processor")
            self.b4.clicked.connect(processor)
            
            self.l5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            self.l5.setObjectName('l5')
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.l5, 3, 1, 1, 2)       # +++
            self.l5.setText(f"Number of starts: {number}")

# !!! vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv            
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000 * 5,     self.end_program)
#                                    1000 * 60 * 5  --> пять минут           
        else:
            self.end_program()
        
    def end_program(self):
        self.l1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.l1.setObjectName('l1')
        self.l1.setText("Buy the full version of the program!")
        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.l1)

#  здесь, если вам надо, установить -------------------------->   '10'
#                                                                 vvvv
#  ...                                                            vvvv
#  winreg.SetValueEx(sub_key, "NamberOfStarts", 0, winreg.REG_SZ, '10')        

# !!! ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Stylesheet = '''
QWidget {
    background : lightyellow;
}
QPushButton {
    background : lightgreen;  
    font-size : 20px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 70px;
}
#l1 {
    font-size : 50px;
}
#l5 {
    font-size : 20px;
}
'''



if __name__ == "__main__":
    SPLab()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)
    mwin = MainWindow()
    mwin.show()
    print("start")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**:

> я заметил, что после перезапуска программа опять работает. Можно как-то привязать время к реестру чтобы второй раз уже нельзя было запустить?
>
> не очень понимаю куда вставить эту строчку, можете объяснить?

```
import winreg
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from PyQt5.Qt import *                                

number, start_program = "", True


def software():
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as hkey:
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "SOFTWARE") as sub_key:
            try:
                i = 0
                while True:
                    path_value = winreg.EnumKey(sub_key, i)
                    print(f"{i} - {path_value}")
                    i += 1
            except OSError as e:
                print(f'OSError: ------------- {e}')
        winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
    winreg.CloseKey(hkey)


def read_key_software():
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as hkey:
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run") as sub_key:
            try:
                i = 0
                while True:
                    path_value = winreg.EnumValue(sub_key, i)
                    print(f"{path_value}")
                    i += 1
            except OSError:
                print("")
        winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
    winreg.CloseKey(hkey)


def matherboard():
    name_board = "BaseBoardProduct"
    n_b = True
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as hkey:
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\BIOS") as sub_key:
            try:
                i = 0
                while n_b:
                    path_value = winreg.EnumValue(sub_key, i)
                    if name_board == path_value[0]:
                        print(f"Matherboard: {path_value[1]}")
                        n_b = False
                    else:
                        i += 1
            except OSError:
                print("matherboard not found")
        winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
    winreg.CloseKey(hkey)
    print("")


def processor():
    name_proc = "ProcessorNameString"
    n_p = True
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as hkey:
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\CentralProcessor\\0") as sub_key:
            try:
                i = 0
                while n_p:
                    path_value = winreg.EnumValue(sub_key, i)
                    if name_proc == path_value[0]:
                        print(f"Proseccor: {path_value[1]}")
                        n_p = False
                    else:
                        i += 1
            except OSError:
                print("processor not found")
        winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
    winreg.CloseKey(hkey)
    print("")


def SPLab(blocking=False):                                          # +++ blocking=False
    global number, start_program
    path = False
    
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER) as hkey:
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "SOFTWARE") as sub_key:
            winreg.CreateKey(sub_key, "SPLab")
    winreg.CloseKey(hkey)
    
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER) as hkey:
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "SOFTWARE\\SPLab", 0, winreg.KEY_READ) as sub_key:
            try:
                num = winreg.EnumValue(sub_key, 0)
                path = True
                start = num[1]
                if int(start) >= 10:
                    start_program = False
            except OSError:
                path = False
        winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "SOFTWARE\\SPLab", 0, winreg.KEY_WRITE) as sub_key:
            if path:
                start = int(start) + 1
            else:
                start = "1"

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv            
            if blocking: 
                winreg.SetValueEx(sub_key, "NamberOfStarts", 0, winreg.REG_SZ, '10')
            else:
                winreg.SetValueEx(sub_key, "NamberOfStarts", 0, winreg.REG_SZ, str(start))
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           
            
        winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
    winreg.CloseKey(hkey)
    number = start
    print("")


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Program")
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget(self)                   
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)            
        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)   

        if start_program:
            self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.b1, 1, 1)        
            self.b1.setText("software")
            self.b1.clicked.connect(software)
            
            self.b2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.b2, 1, 2)       
            self.b2.setText("read_key_software")
            self.b2.clicked.connect(read_key_software)
            
            self.b3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.b3, 2, 1)      
            self.b3.setText("matherboard")
            self.b3.clicked.connect(matherboard)
            
            self.b4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.b4, 2, 2)      
            self.b4.setText("processor")
            self.b4.clicked.connect(processor)
            
            self.l5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            self.l5.setObjectName('l5')
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.l5, 3, 1, 1, 2)  
            self.l5.setText(f"Number of starts: {number}")

          
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000 * 5,     self.end_program)
#                                    1000 * 60 * 5  --> пять минут           
        else:
            self.end_program()
        
    def end_program(self):
        self.l1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.l1.setObjectName('l1')
        self.l1.setText("Buy the full version of the program!")
        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.l1)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv            
       
        SPLab(blocking=True)                               # !!! <---- 

# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Stylesheet = '''
QWidget {
    background : lightyellow;
}
QPushButton {
    background : lightgreen;  
    font-size : 20px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 70px;
}
#l1 {
    font-size : 50px;
}
#l5 {
    font-size : 20px;
}
'''



if __name__ == "__main__":
    SPLab()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)
    mwin = MainWindow()
    mwin.show()
    print("start")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: ОЧЕНЬ помогли, спасибо!

Comment: @arnold пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: я заметил, что после перезапуска программа опять работает. Можно как-то привязать время к реестру чтоб второй раз уже нельзя было запустить?

Comment: @arnold я же вам написал в комментариях, если вам надо, установите `winreg.SetValueEx(sub_key, "NamberOfStarts", 0, winreg.REG_SZ, '10')`

Comment: не очень понимаю куда вставить эту строчку, можете объяснить?

Comment: прошу помогите пожалуйста)))

Comment: @arnold я уже давно добавил обновление в свой ответ.

Comment: Спасибо БОЛЬШОЕ!

Comment: @arnold пожалуйста